# AttributeError: undefined symbol when importing own c compiled function in python

Tags: python, ctypes, numba

I'm trying to domesticate the `numba` `cfunc` compiler ;)

This here is my base_model.py file (the source of my function).

```
import numpy
import numba
import numba.pycc

cc = numba.pycc.CC('base_model')
cc.verbose = True
@cc.export('cumulativeMin','float64[:](float64[:])')  
def cumulativeMin(A):
    r = numpy.empty(len(A))
    t = numpy.inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = numpy.minimum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

Then I do (in the terminal, I run ubuntu):

```
$ python3 base_module.py 
base_model.py:3: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: The 'pycc' module is pending deprecation. Replacement technology is being developed.

Pending Deprecation in Numba 0.57.0. For more information please see: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-the-numba-pycc-module
  import numba.pycc
```

then I do (in python):

```
import numpy
import ctypes


mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
array = numpy.random.uniform(-1,0,1000)
mylib.cumulativeMin(array)
```

then I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 7
      5 mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
      6 array = numpy.random.uniform(-1,0,1000)
----> 7 mylib.cumulativeMin(array)

File /usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py:387, in CDLL.__getattr__(self, name)
    385 if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
    386     raise AttributeError(name)
--> 387 func = self.__getitem__(name)
    388 setattr(self, name, func)
    389 return func

File /usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py:392, in CDLL.__getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    391 def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 392     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    393     if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    394         func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal

AttributeError: ./base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cumulativeMin
```

#Edit:

I would like this function (cummulativeMin) to be compiled ahead of time (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you are supposed to import numba/pycc generated code.

`ctypes` is for using external library, not compiled for python.
It is simpler to build, sure (especially for C coders. You just code C like usually, without caring about python, and let ctypes — with some help from explicit wrapping — handle it).  You can even use any already existing .so not written from that purpose. But it is also less sure. You can segfault easily just by giving wrong argument. And you have to manage C world memory by yourself. And can't mess directly with python data.

Here this is cpython extension. So "pure python" functions written in C, if I may use this oxymoron. Functions that use python memory management (garbage collector) to create python data.
Harder to write, since you have to read and write python internal data format (with the provided python API, sure).
But of course, a better choice when code is generated anyway.

Whatever the criteria, anyway, point is, it is a python module, that is supposed to be imported in python code, that has access to cpython api.

Long story short:

```py
import base_model
base_model.cumulativeMin(...)
```

is the way you are supposed to use it.

## Edit

Since my answer was, I am pretty sure, not understood, I explicit it more (even if that is mostly by repeating the question)

What I did is

Create `MySource.py` file

```py
import numpy
import numba
import numba.pycc

cc = numba.pycc.CC('base_model')
cc.verbose = True
@cc.export('cumulativeMin','float64[:](float64[:])')  
def cumulativeMin(A):
    r = numpy.empty(len(A))
    t = numpy.inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = numpy.minimum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

Then I do (in the terminal, I run ubuntu):

```bash
$ python3 MySource.py 
MySource.py:3: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: The 'pycc' module is pending deprecation. Replacement technology is being developed.

Pending Deprecation in Numba 0.57.0. For more information please see: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-the-numba-pycc-module
  import numba.pycc
```

then I do (in python):

```py
import numpy
import base_model
array = numpy.random.uniform(-1,0,1000)
base_model.cumulativeMin(array)
```

And I get no error, but the result

```py
array([-0.00492896, -0.80422352, -0.80422352, -0.80422352, -0.80422352,
       -0.80422352, -0.8844663 , -0.8844663 , -0.8844663 , -0.8844663 ,
       -0.8844663 , -0.90776422, -0.90776422, -0.90776422, -0.90776422,
...
       -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223,
       -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223, -0.99972223])
```

Note that, outside what is my main answer (don't load it with ctypes, load it with import), I've changed only one thing in my answer: I've changed the name of the source file, from `base_model.py` to `mySource.py`.
To make one point clear: what `import base_model` imports here is the `.so` not a `.py` file. It IS the compiled file that is loaded.

Comment: hello, I would like the function to be compiled ahead of time. So the route you propose does not work for my use case. I'm adding this requirement to the question.

Comment: @user189035 I don't think you understood my answer. I am not proposing any route. And this IS compilation ahead of time. I am just saying that the way to import the `.so` you've generated is not `ctypes.cdll.loadlibrary("basemodel.so")` (approx). But is `import base_model`. That's all. That is the way you load the `basemodel.so` you've compiled ahead of times.

Comment: @user189035 I've just realized that maybe you believe that by `import base_model` is importing the source file (called `base_model.py` or `base_module.py` in your question, depending on the place). This is not the case. In my answer, the source file is called "MySource.py". `base_model` is the name of the generated module. The thing that escapes you, I think, is that `import` DOES import `.so`. When those `.so` are cpython extensions. Which is the case of pycc generated `.so`.

Comment: thanks for having taken the time to clarify your answer. I was indeed initially confused in exactly the way you described. One final thing. On my system, running MySource.py generates a .so file base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, which I had to rename to base_model.so to be able to import into python

Comment: @user189035 That's strange. On my system it does create exactly the same file (`base_model.cypthon-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`). But I don't need to rename it. This is a `base_model.ARCH.so` pattern, so it should be loadable with just `import base_model`.

Comment: @user189035 Are you sure you are using the same python (3.10) to compile and to then to load? The exact same thing happens if I don't. If I use python, say, 3.10, both to compile and then to use, then, no renaming is needed. `base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is loaded by `import base_model`. But if I use python 3.10 to compile, and then try in python 3.8 to `import base_model`, it doesn't work. If then, I rename `mv base_model.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so base_model.so`, then I can `import base_model` even with python 3.8.

Comment: @user189035 That being said, I wouldn't do that. Because there is no guaranteed that a `.so` compiled by python 3.10 doesn't rely on something specific to python 3.10 in the  API. Yet again, it is not like with ctypes, where a function is just an external C function, and python/ctypes, whatever its version, does whatever it wants to call it. Here, your `cumulativeMin` function does call some python functions (such as `PyNumber_Float`) to work, that are provided by python executable. So if the executable is not the same that the one for which the module was compiles, can't be sure.

Comment: @user189035 It is the same, but reversed, that when trying to use a .so for a program `myexec`, that requires `libmylib.5.so` but you have only `libmylib.4.so`. If you rename `mv libmylib.4.so libmylib.5.so` it may work. But that is dangerous, because maybe `myexec` was relying on behaviour of `mylib` that are present only in version 5. Here it is the same. Except that it is the executable that is not the expected one, and the `.so` that expect symbols and behaviors from it. By renaming it, you trick the `.so` to be loaded in the wrong version exec.

Comment: @user189035 so, be sure that you use the exact same python for both compiling and running. And avoid needing to rename the `.so`, if that was really the problem.

Comment: @user189035 Note that you can compile different version. Just run `MySource.py` with different python interpreter versions (or different architectures) and you'll end up with different `so`. Then `import base_model` will pick up the correct one